# parse error in /var/lib/dpkg/status: `Depends' field, invalid package name `python:any'

Tags: dpkg

How can I fix the following error?

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 194 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

dpkg: parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 142 package 'python-pkg-resources':
 `Depends' field, invalid package name `python:any': character `:' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

---

I ran this command

```
head -142 /var/lib/dpkg/status | tail
```

and got this output:

```
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 182
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: python-setuptools
Version: 3.3-1ubuntu1
Provides: python2.7-setuptools
Depends: python:any (>= 2.7), python:any (<< 2.8)
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of: `head -142 /var/lib/dpkg/status | tail`?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Did you install any packages that weren't from Ubuntu itself?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 trusty

Comment: Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 182
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: python-setuptools
Version: 3.3-1ubuntu1
Provides: python2.7-setuptools
Depends: python:any (>= 2.7), python:any (<< 2.8)

Comment: 14.04 lts trusty

Comment: I checked on Debian testing and Ubuntu trusty, none has problem with `python:any`